# GMAP views: Use marker field

Tags: 7, views, google-maps

I have a working GMAP view and I'd like to customize the markers basing on a list field.

I can't find documentations about this feature, in the settings of my view I setted

```
Marker Handling--> Use marker field
```

and

```
Field --> "myfield"
```

What I'd like to know is: does "myfield" has to be an image field or whatelse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [IP Geolocation Views & Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) module. Partial quote from its project page:

> Despite what the name may suggest, IP Geolocation Views & Maps (IPGV&M) is first and foremost a mapping engine.
>
> The module makes it very easy to create Views-based mapping solutions using the map renderer of your choice (**Google**, **OpenLayers** or **Leaflet**) with any location storage module of your choice, e.g.:
>
> - [Get Locations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations),
> - [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield),
> - [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation)
> - [Location](http://drupal.org/project/location).

[image]

> This allows you to bring together modules and feature sets that without IPGV&M you would not be able to combine.
>
> Like beautiful animated [marker clustering on Google or Bing or Mapbox ...](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_markercluster) any of various [map providers](http://drupal.org/project/leaflet_more_maps).
>
> But more importantly IPGV&M adds some features you won't find as conveniently packaged elsewhere.
>
> These include [marker differentiation based on field values or ranges](http://flink.com.au/ramblings/spruce-your-map-markers-font-icons) (2nd screenshot) with or without font icons, various centering options, super-imposing the current visitor's location, allowing multiple content types to be displayed on the same map, full screen button and mini-map inset (bottom screenshot), polygon support (Geofield), marker tags and tool tips and cross-highlighting of associated content on the page when markers are hovered (and vice versa).

[image]

Head over to its (impressive) project page for even more information about it (it would be way too long to include a quote of it all here). That project page also includes various screenshots.

**Note**: Uploading custom markers should be possible also, similar to what you can see in the [screenprint](https://www.drupal.org/files/custom%20markers.jpg) in the feature request about [Custom markers](https://www.drupal.org/node/1985952).

Comment: Yes but I have to test your guide first

Comment: I tried this module today: it's amazing and really simple to use! Thank you again Pierre, you saved me a lot of time!!!

Comment: @SmurfXXX merci for the extra feedback. What else can I say, except something like "thanks for also confirming what I always recommend for these kind of questions!" Ps about the time you saved: it doesn't even get invoiced ...